# Why using the data and error on the subscribe/observable like this is now deprecated in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, deprecated

Why is this code deprecated? and how is the correct form?

```
 getPeopleFunction() {
this.peopleService.getPeopleService().subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

}

Comment: Give some more context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this format now:

```
this.peopleService.getPeopleService().subscribe({
    next: (v) => console.log(v),
    error: (e) => console.error(e),
    complete: () => console.info('complete') 
})
```

https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Comment: When passing in an object like it, it's acceptable to define any of the given properties as long as you define at least 1 of them. Though if you're only going to define `next,` it's still idiomatic to just pass in an lambda function without wrapping it with an object.